# SoapClient: how to pass multiple elements with same name?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have following code:

```
$telnums = array(10, 20, 30);
$obj = new StdClass();
$obj->telnums = new StdClass();
foreach ($telnums as $telnum) {
    $obj->telnums = $telnum;
}

call_user_func(array($this->client, 'createDomain'), new SoapVar($obj, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT));
```

There $this->client is an instance of SoapClient class.

And it generates following request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="...">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:createDomain>
            <createDomainRequest>
                <telnums>30</telnums>
            </createDomainRequest>
        </ns1:createDomain>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But I need

```
            <createDomainRequest>
                <telnums>10</telnums>
                <telnums>20</telnums>
                <telnums>30</telnums>
            </createDomainRequest>
```

How I can achieve this?

P.S.: PHP 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.5 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2010 22:25:33)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you overwrite $obj->telnums at every cycle in foreach.

Comment: @fabrik: yes, but I don't know how to add 3 elements with same name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it by extends SoapClient and overrides __doRequest() method where I modify request as descibed here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php#57995

Looks terrible for me, but it works "right here, right now".

Comment: Ugh. This is horrible, but as far as I can tell, it's the only way to make this work in some cases. It seems like this is a very common problem, which makes me wonder why this hasn't been addressed in the SoapClient already??

Answer (score 15):

I had landed into a similar scenario recently and I found this pattern usually does the trick.

```
$obj = new StdClass();
foreach ($telnums as $telnum) {
    $obj->telnums[] = $telnum;
}
```

The reason this works is because it closely emulates the same data structure as prescribed by your WSDL

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes, this is the day to do it and fixed my issue after hours and hours of attempts.

Comment: Glad it helped. I had wasted so many hours myself trying to figure this out

Comment: Doesn't work... this is same as ARRAY... it depends on the receiving server if they can handle it

Answer (score 9):

The correct answer should have been:

```
$options = array(
  'createDomainRequest' => array(
    'telnums' => array(
      '10',
      '20',
      '30'
    )
  )
);
```

:)

Comment: This is actually incorrect as it results in:

<createDomainRequest>
 <telnums>
  <0>10</0>
  <1>20</1>
  <2>30</2>
 </telnums>
</createDomainRequest>

Comment: The problem here is that associative arrays in php can't have identical keys for obvious reasons. For non SoapClient situations, I managed to work around this by building a custom array to xml conversion class that can handle multiple child elements with the same name, and produces the correct xml output. So, how can we fix the SoapClient so that it can do that as well? The override on __doRequest() is undesirable. Surely this has been encountered before...

Comment: Only that it doesn't produce XML that matches what the question stated. This method works fine if you can control the parsing end, but usually remote services tend to be very explicit and don't handle variations in the document structure very well.

Comment: Have you tried this method before? It works for me - and I don't control the parsing end. Parsers seem to like them just fine.

Comment: I have, and it produces XML output like that which I wrote in my initial comment. Maybe some remote services are designed to accept this discrepancy, but most of the ones I have encountered do not. When subscribing to SOAP services, WSDLs describe exactly how the XML elements are to be ordered. Unfortunately, PHP's built-in SoapClient is subject to the limitations of PHP's associative arrays, in that you can't add more than one key of the same name. The only way to work around it (that I know of currently) is to modify the XML document after-the-fact.

Comment: Thanks.
Works fine for 
<ChildrenAges>           
            <Age>5</Age>
   <Age>8</Age>
   <Age>9</Age>     
 </ChildrenAges>

Comment: This is the proper way to do this. Tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pain in the buttock to find a working solution, but eventually it's not that hard. Even surprisingly easy and neat by using SoapParam's:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$soapClient->__call('createDomain', array(
    new SoapParam('10', 'telnums'),
    new SoapParam('20', 'telnums'),
    new SoapParam('30', 'telnums'),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code format that I used:

```
$wsdl = 'https://your.api/path?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$multipleSearchValues = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$queryData = ['yourFieldName' => $multipleSearchValues];
$results = $client->YourApiMethod($queryData);
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$telnums=array(10, 20, 30);
$createDomainRequest=array('createDomainRequest' => array(
  'telnums' => $telnums)
);
```